# error=TooManyMessages GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I started to implement GCM.

I'm using the [official tutorial by Google](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).

I found NOTHING about this error on Google. Does anybody know what is it means?

I got it from the BroadcastReceiver:

```
if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        Log.i(TAG, "Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());


07-11 16:56:55.083: I/GCMDemo(3425): Send error: Bundle[{error=TooManyMessages, message_type=send_error, google.message_id=1}]
```

Comment: If you do not get a definitive answer here, try the `android-gcm` Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-gcm

Comment: I got the same problem.Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you sent more than 100 messages without collapse key to the same device while the device was offline. Once that limit was reached, the GCM server discarded the stored messages, and sent `TooManyMessages` error to the device when it got back online.

> Note: There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync.

Answer (score 0):

You receive this message on the device when you are trying to upstream a message from it to CCS, and the out queue is already full.
This local queue is filled by messages GCM can't send, because of network unavailability.
Here you probably filled the queue and restart the app (which is why you messageId is 1).
A limit of 20 unsent messages per application is kept on the device (discovered this by testing, not stated anywhere AFAIK).